# .htaccess to remove file extension not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have public html folder where some files and folders are stored. Then I have created a Folder In It. That Folder Contains Some Files And A Folder "Admin" which containes files related to my admin panel to surf my site members data.

Now I used Following Code In .htaccess file in public html folder which removes all pages's php extension.But When I try To Log In To My Admin Panel, Log In Fails.

e.g. **www.abc.com** >> Here .htaccess file Is with following code.

It works For Files in **www.abc.com** and for files in **www.abc.com/xyz/index.php** and other files. But When Tried **www.abc.com/xyz/admin/index.php** For Login, This Page just get refreshed But Doesn't allowing successful login.

Code used in .htaccess is as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index([/.]|$) /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules that avoid redirecting for `POST` requests:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:php|html)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index([/.]|$) /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Yes...It worked...Thanx...But how can use code to remove .html extension too ?